# Issue with Schulding tasks to run everyday at 12am - Java

Tags: java, timer

I want to run a task very day at 12am.
my current code looks like this:

```
 long currennTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long stopTime = currennTime + 2000; //provide the 2hrs time it should execute 1000*60*60*2
        while(stopTime != System.currentTimeMillis())
        {

My task();
}

 private static Date getTomorrowMidNight()
    {
        Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
        c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0); //anything 0 - 23
        c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        Date midnight = c.getTime();

        return midnight;
    }


    public static void startTask(){
        Timer_Tasks task = new Timer_Tasks();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(task,getTomorrowMidNight(),1000*10);
    }



    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        startTask();
    }
```

the task keep running more then once every 24h, where could be the problem?

Thank you

Comment: You set the third parameter (```period - time in milliseconds between successive task executions.```) of the timer to 1000*10. Which means this task will run every 10000 milliseconds. If you want to run this task once per day set it to 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 or 86400000.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Rashin's comment I would also recommend not using `while(stopTime != System.currentTimeMillis())`. That is a very specific clause, the process may not check the time on that exact millisecond. It would be easy to get stuck in that loop.

A better way is to check if your timeout has passed:

```
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
long stopTime = start + 2000;
while(end-start<stopTime) {
    My task();
    end = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Another option is to annotate your method with @Scheduled annotation from spring along with the required CRON expression.
eg:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 00 00 * * ?")
public void doSomething() {}
```

You will have to enable spring scheduling in your application by adding @EnableScheduling  to your configuration for this to work.